# Adding Bootstrap to ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to React and trying to add Bootstrap to my project. I followed the below tutorial in creating my first app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2017

I then tried to add Bootstrap by npm install from the offical site and adding the import line of code to app.tsx file:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

I also added "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4" to my package. However when I try to add a button to my app.tsx file, I get errors i.e.

```
<div>  <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button> </div>
```

Errors:
build: JSX expression must have one parent element.
TS17004 (TS) Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
Build:Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

I am not sure exactly why this is happening.

Comment: can you share the render() method you wrote

Comment: Its the same one as the tutorial except I added the button tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1>Welcome to React!!</h1>
              <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

> JSX expression must have one parent element. TS17004 (TS).

The above error occurs when you are having multiple JSX elements inside the `return()`.
To get rid of that, you can wrap all the elements inside a `<div>` tag.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button>
            <h1>Welcome to React!!</h1>
         </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Alternatively, from React 16, there is something called `<React.Fragments>`. This is a better approach as you don't need to add an extra dom-node.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Primary</Button>
            <h1>Welcome to React!!</h1>
         </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And, one more I would like to mention: you don't need to use node's require syntax, you use `import` of ES6.

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to why no bootstrap buttons are appearing

Comment: @Mguy Can you share the code-sample so that I can look into the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<Button>` is wrapped with a `div`, your elements should be wrapped in a parent element.

Since React 16.2 you can also use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

**EDIT:**

Also make your your `tsconfig.json` includes `"jsx": "react"`;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
    "app.tsx"
  ]
}
```